# ios activate scrolling on login form when keyboard appeared

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

here is the simplest case when I might need scrolling on ios, I'm looking for coding less solution working at least on iOS 6 and 7

So, classic login form:

[image]

And after starting editing user realised he need to register first, so he should be able to scroll down to corresponding button

[image]

What is simplest way to activate scrolling in this case, preferably using storyboard visual editor?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your components to `UIScrollView`, then set it's `contentSize` property to the bottom of register button:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, Button.frame.origin.y+Button.frame.size.height);
```

If the contentSize height of scroll less than or equal to it's height, scroll will not be scrollable. All you should do is to decrease it's height than the keyboard is shown and increase again than not.

For doing this you have to add observer for notifications `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`, for example in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

And the methods of handling notifications:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow{
     scroll.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height-220);
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide{
     scroll.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height+220);
}
```

220 px - is the height of the keyboard.

Comment: Notice that in landscape the height of the keyboard is different

Comment: Thanks, I got most close behaviour to what I need, currently digging how to find out keyboard width programmatically

Comment: I think this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298688/keyboard-size-given-by-nsnotificationcenter

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that just in storyboard. You have to include the whole view inside UIScrollView and watch for keyboard event to get the keyboard size, then subtract that height from the scrollview height.

First, you have to declare your view controller as a text field delegate.

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Now you have to add a text delegate method that will be called when you focus on a field and a keyboard appears.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

This will allow you to scroll inside the scroll view when the keyboard appears. If you have any question regarding how scroll view works, feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: So root view of LoginViewController should be ScrollView with UIView as subview, correct?

Comment: That's right. If you don't do that, there will be no scrolling at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I got different effect, before I clicked on edit text area was scrollable, and after I did click and contentSize of scroll changed - scroll became disabled

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, you can click on UIScrollView and then in the right part you can select 'On Drag' or 'Interactive' for Keyboard section.

So run and try;
When keyboard is appeared and you scroll the view, then keyboard will disappear.

Good luck!